# Is session in php reset on every page load?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to extend the session lifetime to 3 days by using the script below.

```
 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',3*24*60*60);
 ini_set('session.gc_probability',1);
 ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);

 $sessionCookieExpireTime = 3*24*60*60;
 session_set_cookie_params($sessionCookieExpireTime);
 session_start();

 // page code
```

The session lifetime has to remain for 3 days, and on the end of the 3rd day session has to expire. Here my questions are,

1) Is the session reset on every page load?

2) Am I extending the lifetime to 3 days on every page reload?

If yes, I don't want to extend the session lifetime on every page load. It should set for the first time the page accessed by the user and it should expire on 3rd day end. It should not reset the session lifetime on every time the page reload.

The session has to reset only on the 3rd day end when the session expires. Till then no reset should be performed.

Plz help me on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, session is not reset on every page load and it will expire calculating since the time it was first created.

Answer (score 6):

Create a session variable called 'created' which holds the timestamp of the moment when the variable was created. Now on every page load you check if 3 days have passed. If 3 days have passed you unset the session variables and destroy the session.

```
<?php

session_start();

$expiry = 60 * 60 * 24 * 3; // 3 days

if (!isset($_SESSION['created'])) {
    // Session variable 'created' doesn't exist, let's create one for the session
    $_SESSION['created'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['created'] > $expiry) {
    // More than 3days has passed since the timestamp in 'created' session variable. Destroy the session.
    // Here you could also unset any other session variables you had. I am unsetting the 'created' variable.
    unset($_SESSION['created']);
    session_destroy();
}

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why for heaven's sake would you want that? Now let's say some user uses your program on every workday (Mon to Sat) in every week.

So he may start using your program on monday, the session is to wednesday. On wednesday the session is refreshed until saturday. On saturday the session is refreshed until tuesday. On tuesday the session is refreshed until friday, on friday until sunday, and then booooom -> new login required.

This behaviour is WTF, since the user can't determine why he is logged out between saturday and monday in one week, but not in the other.

Comment: this is not using for login system, this is using to cache the server response data and it should reset for every 3 days.